# OpenGL sprite half pixel position offset

Tags: c++, opengl

Recently I noticed that even though I create textures with width and height in pixels without fractional part, they seem a little blurry. After hours of debugging I found, that the problem lies in offsets.
If I provide offsets without fractional part I get this:
[image]

But if I add offsets with fractional part, I get:
[image]

**Please see these images in their full size, otherwise you won't notice the problem :)**

I have this method for setting texture:

```
bool WindowsGraphicsManager::setTexture(
    UINT32& id, UINT8* image, UINT32 width, UINT32 height,
    bool wrapURepeat, bool wrapVRepeat, bool useMipmaps, int textureType)
{
    glGenTextures(1, &id);
    bindTexture(id);
    int type = GL_RGBA;
    if (textureType == Texture::MONO) {
        type = GL_ALPHA;
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    }
    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, type,
        width, height, 0, type,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    int minFilter = GL_LINEAR;
    if (useMipmaps) {
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        minFilter = GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR;
    }
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, minFilter);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    int wrap_u = wrapURepeat ?
        GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
    int wrap_v = wrapVRepeat ?
        GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, wrap_u);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, wrap_v);
    return !checkGLError("Loading texture.");
}
```

I know that a little bit of bluriness is expected, but this seems like too much and is way too noticable.
What could I do to solve this, or at least where should I look for the problem? Shader? Matrix? Model? Texture? Render settings?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "width and height in pixels without fractional part". The size of the texture in pixels can't have a fractional part. Are you talking about the coordinates you use for drawing the textures? That's not really shown in the posted code. Pixel centers in OpenGL are at half integer coordinates, so 200.5 is indeed the coordinate of a pixel center.

Comment: By "without fractional part" I mean width and height is 100.0px instead of 100.5px or so. Yes texture always have widths and heights without fraction parts, but I'm talking about translation matrix which can and will have widths with fractional part, as well as position offset.

Comment: @SMart: This is really a difficult topic. Viewport space pixel centers are on x+0.5. However when you draw a quad (with a texture on it), you don't want it's edges "cut" through the pixel centers, but align with the pixel edges. That's the reason why pixel centers are placed on ….5 in the first place, so that quads with vertex coordinates at ….0 will align nicely for the rasterizer. But it doesn't stop there: The edges of a texture are at coordinates 0 and 1, which means all the pixels of a texture always have their center coordinates at some fractional value.

Comment: @SMart: Getting all of this to align perfectly can become troublesome. If all you want is a perfect 1:1 viewport pixel → texture pixel mapping, then your best bet is writing a fragment shader that uses `texelFetch` with the texture coordinate being the fragment position, with some offset applied; of course no rotation or scaling in that situation, but sometimes you just want to display an image as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your actual texture. Just make sure you round your coordinates before rendering. What you're seeing here (together with the weird looking stretching) are rounding errors.

Comment: But what about a situation where I need to fill the screen of 301 pixels width with three squares? I'll have to use offsets of 0, 100.3333333 and 200.6666666 as well as texture widths of 100.333333. I assume this will not look so good. Any tips on smoothing that?

Comment: Antialiasing, multisamping, etc. Trial and error. There's no way to do this with 100% pixel accuracy/sharp borders simply due to the way OpenGL does subpixel rendering.

Comment: Use "squares" of size 100 101 and 100 if you want no blur

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to copy textures to the screen in a pixel accurate way, and can use at least OpenGL 3.0, there is a much easier way: Use `glBlitFramebuffer()`. To use this, you create an FBO, bind it as the read framebuffer, attach the texture to it, and copy. No need to worry about shaders, transformations, or anything. And it will probably be more efficient as well.

To do this, create an FBO once during initialization:

```
GLuint fboId = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
```

Then, anytime you want to draw a texture with id `texId`, width `w` and height `h` at position `(x, y)` of your window:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                       GL_TEXTURE2D, texId, 0);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, w, h,
                  x, y, x + w, x + h,
                  GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

You can scale the texture during this copy if you want, by using different sizes for the source and target rectangles. In that case, use `GL_LINEAR` for the last argument instead of `GL_NEAREST`.